# how to retrieve the bill list from xero api

Tags: xero-api

I am working on [xero-api](http://www.xero.com) and have successfully retrieved the invoice, contact and payment from the api. But am unable to list out the list out bills from the api.

Comment: please show what you've tried yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bills are also retrieved from the Invoices endpoint so you might be already retrieving them. Bills have a Type of ACCPAY and sales invoices have a type of ACCREC.

So you could make a request like GET /Invoices?where=Type=="ACCPAY" to retrieve only the Bills.